# How to programmatically bring up list of Wifi networks to connect to?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I'm programming a Nexus 7.  In my program I reach a point where I want the user to select a Wifi network to use (either preconfigured or the choice to create a new one).  How can I bring up that dialog programmatically?

Comment: http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137894/how-to-programmatically-get-a-list-of-wireless-ssids-in-range-from-networkmanage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the wi-fi list, you may first need to use the wi-fi permissions.  Wi-Fi must be turned on first before the Wi-Fi scan can provide a list of results.

My guess is: ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

I think the easiest would approach would be to then launch the appropriate intent.
ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK

(May also wish to see: ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)

Answer (score 7):

try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);       
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create your own dialog:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

Gives you a list of the networks and for connecting to a concrete SSID:

```
public void connectToWifi(String ssid) {

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\""; // Please note the quotes.
                                                    // String should contain
                                                    // ssid in quotes

        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        wifiMgr.addNetwork(conf);
        Log.d(PluginConstants.LOG_TAG, ssid+" added");

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
                wifiMgr.disconnect();
                wifiMgr.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiMgr.reconnect();
                Log.d(PluginConstants.LOG_TAG, "conneting to: ssid");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```